# Get a smaller list of lists from a list of lists of equal length based on criteria using Python

Tags: python-3.x, list

Good evening,

I have a table in the format of a list of lists. Each list is of the same length. I would like to obtain a smaller list based on the unique values of the numbers (1 list per number whichever shows up first).

```
tbl = [[1, 'aaa'], [2, 'aab'], [3, 'aac'], [4, 'GGC'], [4, 'GGH'], [6, 'GGS'], [7, 'aad']]
```

I've tried the following snippet of code:

```
tbl_simple = [list(x) for x in set(tuple(x) for x in tbl)]
```

But this line treats the whole list as one big unique value and I end up with the same table. I would like to filter on just the condition of the number (or some column of my choosing). The final result would look like this:

```
[[1, 'aaa'], [2, 'aab'], [3, 'aac'], [4, 'GGC'], [6, 'GGS'], [7, 'aad']]
```

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy non-one liner would be:

```
output = []
seen = set()
for num, letters in tbl:
    if num in seen:
        continue
    output.append([num, letters])
    seen.add(num)
```

Still thinking about a one-liner.

Comment: Changed seen={} to seen=set() but overall this works which is what I need at the moment. Unfortunately I have 20 columns in the real-world example... but thank you for your time.

Comment: @MechEE
Sorry for that, fixed.
If you have 20 columns and it's only by the first, you can take out the first like so: `for row in tbl: if row[0] in seen ...`

Comment: My philosophy currently is "Make it work correctly, make the source code clear, make it run quickly." so you got me to the first level. I had to hard code the column I want to sort by as a 6. Thanks again for your help.